# AjaxControlToolkit Twitter control causes error

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I added AjaxControlToolkit 4.0 to my project and added to Toolbox. Then I added Twitter control, just double clicked on it and didn't add anything else. But yellow page comes with:

```
  Server Error in '/' Application.
    The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control 
contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).
```

No page is mentioned in error. Do I need to add anything else to make it work? My code is like this:

```
 <asp:Twitter ID="Twitter1" runat="server"></asp:Twitter>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Appearently, we cannot use this control without `ToolkitScriptManager`. But this doesn't solve the error.

There was some if conditions in `<% %>` brackets in `<head runat="server"> ... </head>` section, I had to remove them. And added `Page.Header.DataBind();` to the `page_load` to make it work.

This is how I added it to MasterPage. Hope it helps someone.